# Simple python login program

Tags: python

```
UserList = []
PassList = []

print("Welcome to GipCo/n")

ans = input("Do you have an account with GipCo? please enter y/n:")

if ans == 'n':
    User = input("Please type your username: ")
    UserList.append(User)
    Pass = input("Please type your password: ")
    PassList.append(Pass)
    print(UserList,PassList)
    print("You have created your new accoutn with GipCo, please login\n")
    User1 = input("Please enter your username: ")
    Pass1 = input("Please enter your password: ")
    if User1 == (UserList) and Pass1 == (PassList):
        print("Welcome to GipCo, type MENU to enter: ")

    else:
        print("Incorrect username or Password")
```

`

Why wont his work, i enter the username and password in User and Pass which adds it to the list but when logging in it does not call the lists but just says that it is wrong.

Comment: You should focus on breaking this problem up into smaller units of code that perform a well-defined function instead of having this huge chunk of code that tries to do everything all at once.

Comment: "It says that it is wrong" What does it actually say?

Answer (score 2):

`User1` and `Pass1` are strings; `UserList` and `PassList` are, as their names suggest, lists.  No string can be equal to a list.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are comparing `UserList` of type array with a String so it will return false in there:

```
 if User1 == (UserList) and Pass1 == (PassList)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if User1 == (UserList) and Pass1 == (PassList):
```

You haven't done a search in your list(s) for the information

```
if User1 in UserList:     #is User1 in the list? 
   if Pass1 == PassList[UserList.index(User1)]:
      print ("Log in Success")
```